# How to trigger <b-overlay> if child calls an Axios request using vue.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, bootstrap-vue

How to trigger Bootstrap-vue overlay if any child makes a request e.g. using axios. I want to do this automatically, I only need a request to trigger the overlay.

```
 <b-overlay>
   <child>
     <other-child />
   </child>
 </b-overlay>
```

Comment: You may want to use `Vue.$emit` to send an event from the child components to the overlay component. You can also try to use an axios "interceptor" that can catch all requests and responses and tell your app something about them. This method might utilize Vuex to keep track of updates to your app and send them to different components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another option, that you can use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to define global states for managing your app. Of course, if your project is small using `$emit` is maybe a better solution.

There is a sample code that can give you the main idea of Vuex, you need to extend it for your case.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        is_loading: true
    },
    mutations: {
        changeIsLoading(state, value) {
            state.is_loading = value
        },
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @slowFooMovement said in the comment you can have an instance of axios configured to have a request/response interceptor in the request you'll change your app state to loading and in the response, it will be set to not loading.

Here is a basic example https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-leakey-deqr6?file=/src/components/FilmList.vue